# How to install C revision DWA-171 drivers on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, wireless, usb

Im new to linux, I installed yesterday. For windows I just go on the D-LINK website and download the driver .exe setup and install it and it works. When I try to go to the same site for linux drivers and follow the instructions, there is a error with compiling. Does the drivers from the site even work? How can I install the drivers for the usb dongle?

lsusb:
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1532:005c Razer USA, Ltd Razer DeathAdder Elite

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0416:0123 Winbond Electronics Corp. Ducky One2 Mini RGB

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1462:7c56 Micro Star International MYSTIC LIGHT

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1038:12aa SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries Arctis 5

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2001:331d D-Link Corp. DWA-171

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Drivers from the site don't work. Does the dongle  work without drivers? Please add output of `lsusb` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 I edited the question with the lsusb output

Comment: This driver covers your device: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340916/trying-to-install-usb-wifi-device-with-kubuntu-20-04/1342321#1342321 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.